# NuxtJS Cannot read property "property_name" of undefined

Tags: single-page-application, nuxt.js

I am using `this.$router.push('/route/path')` to change routes in nuxt.

However, when I get to the new route, the page gives an error:

```
Nuxt  Cannot read property propertyname of undefined
```

However, the property it is referring to is on the previous page on a component which is not loaded in the current page !

I am using nuxt in SPA mode.

when I use location.replace('/route/path'), I dont get the issue, but obviously we dont want that because then a new page is refreshed.

Comment: Add more detail and code please!!

Comment: sounds like the error happens before the push

Comment: The issue is, in SPA mode, the entire website is loaded onto one page, so when you navigate to a different route, it still has those properties defined, but it seems like the computed properties of the previous page then becomes null and caises these errors...